# How to use stored procedure in jQuery Datatable with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, sql, asp.net-mvc, datatable

```csharp
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoadData()
{
  var client = new RestClient(url);
  var request = new RestRequest("api/abc/GetAllEmployee", Method.GET);
  var response = client.Execute<List<UserViewModel>>(request);   
  var draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw").FirstOrDefault();
  var start = Request.Form.GetValues("start").FirstOrDefault();
  var length = Request.Form.GetValues("length").FirstOrDefault();
  int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
  int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
  int totalRecords = 0;
  var v = (from a in userlist select a);
  totalRecords = v.Count();

  var data = v.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();

  return Json(new 
  { 
    draw = draw, 
    recordsFiltered = totalRecords, 
    recordsTotal = totalRecords,   
    data = data 
  }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

I want to use a stored procedure to do pagination in my jQuery datatable. My SQL Server stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_getdata] 
    @PageNo INT, 
    @NoOfRecord INT, 
    @TotalRecord INT OUTPUT
AS 
    SELECT @TotalRecord = COUNT(*) 
    FROM users 

    SELECT * 
    FROM   
        (SELECT 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY users.userid) AS SrNo, 
             users.userid, 
             users.username, 
             users.employeeid, 
             users.emailid, 
             users.gender, 
             country.countryname 
         FROM 
             users) AS Tab 
         WHERE  
             Tab.srno BETWEEN ((@PageNo - 1) * @NoOfRecord) + 1 AND (@PageNo * @NoOfRecord) 
         ORDER BY 
             Tab.srno ASC 

    RETURN
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Users-data-table").DataTable({
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "processing": true,
    // for show progress bar
    "serverSide": true, // for process server side
    "filter": false, // this is for disable filter (search box)
    "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
    "aLengthMenu": false,
    "ordering": false,
    "info": false,
    "paging": true,
    "info": false,
    "lengthChange": false,
    "ajax": {
      "url": "/Dashboard/LoadData",
      "type": "POST",
      "datatype": "json"
    },
    "columns": [{
      "data": "SrNo",
      "name": "Sr. No.",
      "autoWidth": true
    }, {
      "data": "EmployeeId",
      "name": "Employee ID",
      "autoWidth": true
    }, {
      "data": "UserName",
      "name": "User Name",
      "autoWidth": true
    }, {
      "data": "Gender",
      "name": "Gender",
      "autoWidth": true
    }, {
      "data": "CountryName",
      "name": "Country Name",
      "autoWidth": true
    }, {
      "data": "UserId",
      "render": function(data) {
        return "<a class='editUser' href='@Url.Action("Edit","Dashboard")?id=" + data + "')><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> Edit</a><a href='@Url.Action("Delete","Dashboard")?id=" + data + "'class='deleteUser')><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Delete</a>";
      }
    },],
  });
});
```

I am not getting how to use page no, total records and no. of records in ASP.NET MVC from the stored procedure. How can I use this stored procedure with this data table for pagination?

Answer (score 0):

Add this model to your solution explorer.

```
public class JQueryDataTableParamModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Request sequence number sent by DataTable, same value must be returned in response
        /// </summary>       
        public string sEcho { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Text used for filtering
        /// </summary>
        public string sSearch { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Number of records that should be shown in table
        /// </summary>
        public int iDisplayLength { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// First record that should be shown(used for paging)
        /// </summary>
        public int iDisplayStart { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Number of columns in table
        /// </summary>
        public int iColumns { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Number of columns that are used in sorting
        /// </summary>
        public int iSortingCols { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Comma separated list of column names
        /// </summary>
        public string sColumns { get; set; }

        //public int iPage { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Given below code is for controller and this is the code for total dataTable functionality which includes searching, sorting, pagination etc.

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult LoadData(JQueryDataTableParamModel param)
        {
            ActionResult response = null;
            try
            {

                var verifyList = _repository.GetList();

                var displayRecordCount = 0; //for passing displayed records count(if search is true pass the filtered record count, else pass the entire list count

                IEnumerable<Sp_getdata_Result> filteredVerifyList = null; //used to hold the filtered data of taskList

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.sSearch))
                {
                    string searchText = param.sSearch.ToLower();

                    filteredVerifyList = _repository.GetList()
                                         .Where(c => ((c.username!= null) && c.username.ToLower().Contains(searchText) ||
                    (c.countryname != null) && c.countryname .ToLower().Contains(searchText)));


                    if (filteredVerifyList.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        displayRecordCount = filteredVerifyList.Count();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        displayRecordCount = 0;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    filteredVerifyList = verifyList;
                    displayRecordCount = verifyList.Count();
                }


                int sortColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request["iSortCol_0"]); //Gets the SortColumnIndex from the DataTable on User Interaction

                Func<Sp_getdata_Result, string> orderingFunction = (c => sortColumnIndex == 2 ? Convert.ToString(c.StudentId) :
                                                                                    Convert.ToString(c.FirstName)
                                                                                    ); //Sorts the List based on supplied sortColumn index

                string sortDirection = Request["sSortDir_0"]; // asc or desc

                if (sortDirection == "asc")
                    filteredVerifyList = filteredVerifyList.OrderBy(orderingFunction); //Sort the List in ascending Order and Re assigns to the List
                else
                    filteredVerifyList = filteredVerifyList.OrderByDescending(orderingFunction); //Sort the List in descending Order and Re assigns to the List
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.sSearch)) //If search is null then display the records as seleted in 'records per page' DropDown
                {
                    if (param.iDisplayLength != -1)
                    {
                        filteredVerifyList = filteredVerifyList.Skip(param.iDisplayStart)//skip to start Record in the List which will be supplied as param.iDisplayStart
                                                             .Take(param.iDisplayLength); //Gets up to param.iDisplayLength from param.iDisplayStart record     
                    }
                }              

                var displayedTaskList = filteredVerifyList; // filteredVerifyList;

                var result = from Alert in displayedTaskList
                             select new[] {
                             Convert.ToString(Alert.userid),
                                        Convert.ToString(Alert.username),
                                        Convert.ToString(Alert.employeeid),
                                        Convert.ToString(Alert.emailid),
                                        Convert.ToString(Alert.gender),
                                        Convert.ToString(Alert.countrynam)

                         };

                response = Json(new
                {
                    result= "Success",
                    sEcho = param.sEcho,
                    iTotalRecords = verifyList.Count(),
                    iTotalDisplayRecords = displayRecordCount,
                    aaData = result
                }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;

            }
            return response;
        }
```

Here, I need to clear up two things.
1.`_repository` is nothing but if you are using `Data Repository Pattern` then, that was it's reference. If you are not using repository pattern then you need to insert your table reference and have to call each field parameter of your table with that reference.

2. `GetList()` is my Repository method. Since, I don't know your Repository method name i just placed mine. Instead of mine you can place your's.

Everything was fine with your jquery script but need to add few more lines:

```
 "aLengthMenu": [
                                       [5, 10, 25, 50, -1],
                                       [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]
                    ],

                    "bAutoWidth": true,
                    "bScrollCollapse": true,

                    "iDisplayLength": 5,
                    "pagingType": "simple_numbers",
                    "sDom": 'fl<t>ip',


                    "bJQueryUI": false,
                    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
                    "oLanguage": {
                        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page",
                        "oPaginate": {
                            "sPrevious": "Prev",
                            "sNext": "Next"
                    },
                    },
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "sAjaxSource": "LoadData",
                    "bProcessing": true,
```